# I want to apply custom styles for highchart plotline labels

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I want to apply custom style highchart plotline label.  I'm using `borderRadiusRight` option but it not applying. 
Following is my code. Please check.

```js
Highcharts.chart('chart', {
  //...
  xAxis: {
    plotLines: [{
      color: 'red',
      width: 2,
      value: sbar,
      dashStyle: 'solid',
      label: {
        y: -6,
        x: 25,
        useHTML: true,
        text: 'Start date',
        textAlign: 'center',
        rotation: 0,
        style: {
          backgroundColor: 'red',
          color: 'white',
          padding: '2px',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          borderRadiusRight: '10px'
        }
      },
    }]

  }
  //...
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no style `borderRadiusRight` in css/highcharts. You have to use `borderRadius` property for this.

Try with `borderRadius: 0 10px 10px 0`

Here first value applies to top-left, second value applies to top-right, third value applies to bottom-right, fourth value applies to bottom-left corners.